# How to override index in ActiveAdmin without has_many relationshisp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have a relation between my model User and Request that is decoupled. I.E. There is no `user_id` field in the `requests` table.I have a finder to figure out what Requests a User can see that is different than the default ActiveAdmin call of

```
requests where user_id = x
```

I had assumed that if I had a method in my User class called `requests` that called this finder, ActiveAdmin would be able to figure it out but it doesn't. So here's some code. I previously assumed this would work to get the requests for the user:

```
class User
...
  def requests
    RequestFinder.new(self).find
  end

...
end
```

Then I got this error:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column requests.user_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...T  1 AS count_column FROM "requests" WHERE "requests"...
```

So I figured I should override the index method in the requests controller:

```
def index
  @requests = RequestFinder.new(current_user).find.page(params[:page]).per(20)
end
```

But then I get the following error:

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:432:in `form_for'
```

I'm not really sure how to reformat my requests controller to render the requests from the finder instead of from the user.

Answer (score 1):

So as per usual I figure it out right after I post #facepalm.

If you want to pass any generic ActiveRecord::Relation to active admin index, just override the `scoped_collection` method making sure to add pagination, like so:

```
controller do 
  def scoped_collection
    RequestFinder.new(current_user).find.page(params[:page]).per(20)
  end
end
```